# Are line breaks in tooltips shown consistently across platforms in SWT

Tags: swt

I would like to have a control with a two-line tooltip. For example a `Label`:

```java
Label label = new Label( parent, SWT.NONE );
label.setText( "label text" );
label.setToolTipText( "one line\nsecond line" );
```

The documentation does not state anything regarding line breaks, however, on Windows, the tooltip shows two lines like desired:

[image]

Now, I would like to know how multi-line tooltips are shown on other platforms, in particular, Gtk3/Linux and macOS.

Comment: Works on macOS, don't know about GTK. If you can use JFace an alternative is to use the `ToolTip` or `DefaultToolTip` classes which give more control.

Comment: @ greg-449 thanks for the macOS confirmation. Regarding JFace tooltips, I prefer the native appearance and currently only need line breaks.

Comment: I can confirm that it works fine on Linux Mint 18.1 with Gtk3.

Comment: @Nobody thanks for your help!

Comment: I used <br> in message.properties file for a text to show as a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize what [@greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) and [@Nobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1740724/nobody) said:

Line breaks in SWT tooltips appear consistently across major platforms: Windows, macOS, and Gtk3/Linux